How can I prompt to run a macro from my PERSONAL.XLSB whenever any Excel workbook containing specific text in the filename opens?
I’m trying to create a VBA solution in Excel that will prompt me to run a specific macro whenever I open a workbook that contains "Action Items" in the filename. Specifically, if the filename includes "Action Items", I’d like Excel to ask me if I want to run a macro called ActionItemReportPro. If I click "Yes," it should run that macro; if "No," it should just open the file as usual.
I want this functionality to be available for any workbook I open, since the PERSONAL.XLSB would open anytime any other excel spreadsheet opens, so not just when I open Excel itself. I placed my code in PERSONAL.XLSB so that it’s accessible across all workbooks. Hopefully excel doesn't have to run in the background open first as in most cases it will be closed and only open when opening a new file.
The code below works fine if I manually trigger it. I initially tried using the Workbook_Open event in PERSONAL.XLSB, but I would need it to trigger when any workbook is opened, not my Personal workbook.
I also considered using the Auto_Open macro in PERSONAL.XLSB, but this only runs once when Excel starts and doesn’t monitor subsequent workbook openings.
After researching, I learned that application-level events might work, so I tried setting up an App_WorkbookOpen event in a class module within PERSONAL.XLSB to listen for each new workbook opened.
Here’s what I have in the class module (EventClassModule) for handling application-level events:
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Wb.Name
    
    ' Check if "Action Items" is in the file name
    If InStr(1, fileName, "Action Items", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Dim userResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
        userResponse = MsgBox("Would you like to run the AIR Macro?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Run AIR Macro")
        
        If userResponse = vbYes Then
            Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!ActionItemReportPro"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

And here’s how I initialize it in ThisWorkbook of PERSONAL.XLSB:
Dim AppEvents As New EventClassModule

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set AppEvents.App = Application
End Sub

After setting this up and restarting Excel, the code doesn’t seem to trigger as expected. My understanding is that the App_WorkbookOpen event should activate every time I open any new workbook in Excel, but it isn’t functioning that way.
Am I missing a step to properly initialize the event in PERSONAL.XLSB? Or is there an alternative approach to ensure that this code checks each new workbook opened after Excel starts? Any guidance would be appreciated! Thank you.

I also think there is a way, however that would present a HUGE security issue (think virus). If you do pursue this route perhaps looking at how these viruses work would give you the answer. Otherwise the file you open should have the code to trigger running the macro.
